# Possible ways for hackers to alter kernel behaviour without root

Tags: rootkits, kernel, root

I'm wondering is it possible to harm kernel (by injecting shared library, loadable module or something like that) without root. If yes, how hackers can achieve it?

Comment: Unless there is a bug you can't do. But [bugs happen](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/471).

Comment: Look up cpu rings. There are some hardware protections that limit the behavior of certain types of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not supposed to be any way for unprivileged users to modify the running kernel. The two ways that such an attack could happen are either to first exploit a bug in a privileged service or setuid binary to give them root (such as [CVE-2010-1646, the secure path vulnerability in sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/alerts/secure_path.html)), or to exploit a bug in the kernel itself (such as [CVE-2017-6074, the DCCP double-free vulnerability](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/471)).